# Visual Studio 2017 solution group files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I recently updated my Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.3 and I realized that my files are not grouping anymore.

Before the update, I had something like this:

- Folder

  - file.component.ts

    - file.component.html
    - file.component.css

Now since the 15.3 visual studio update I have something like this:

- Folder

  - file.component.ts
  - file.component.html
  - file.component.css

Is there any configuration on Visual Studio to restore the first example behavior?

Thanks.